# size image not function using prop <Image/ > on nextJs 13

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I want to adjust the size of the image so that horizontal scroll being active
this my code: first Component

```js
"use client";

import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

const BodyParts = () => {
  return (
    <Image
      className="inline-block p-2 cursor-pointer hover:scale-110 delay-100 transition duration-250 ease-in-out "
      src="/assets/gym.png"
      alt="hero banner"
      width={200}
      height={200}
    />
  );
};

export default BodyParts;
```

Second Component:

```js
<div className=" relative items-center">
      <div
        id="slider"
        className="w-full h-full flex overflow-x-scroll scroll whitespace-nowrap scroll-smooth"
      >
        {data.map((item) => (
          <div
            key={item.id || item}
            itemID={item.id || item}
            title={item.id || item}
          >
            <BodyParts
              item={item}
              bodyPart={bodyPart}
              setBodyPart={setBodyPart}
            />
```

i was using adjust the size on  properti, but not fucntion.